# PGSQL Query to Order by with a specific letter in every user name

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-order-by

I have to write a query that sort (order by) my user names in a way where it should be sorted with a specific letter comes in priority (within the name). 
For example if I have users Lemon, Loger, Alan, Avon, Bland, Cavin, Clauge then my query should return these in following order:

- Lemon
- Loger
- Alan
- Bland
- Clauge
- Avon
- Cavin

i.e. "L" letter should be priority in sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `position` function to extract the position of `l`, and sort according to that. There are, however, two caveats to keep in mind:

1. `position` is case-sensitive, so you'd have to explicitly deal with cases (e.g., by lowercasing the string to search through).
2. If the substring you're searching for (`l`, in this case) isn't in the string, `position` will return `0`, so you'll have to deal with `0` explicitly lest names without Ls come first instead of last:

```
SELECT   name
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY CASE POSITION('l' IN LOWER(name))
              WHEN 0 THEN NULL
              ELSE POSITION('l' IN LOWER(name)) 
         END ASC NULLS LAST,
         name
```

Comment: Thanks @mureinik. The provided query works well for me. :)